# snapping to sections without window scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to snap to sections within a div, however I want to do this without the window scrolling. I want to be able to scroll within that div.

I don't believe I'm explaining myself well enough. When I scroll, the window scrolls, then article is snapped into place, and so on. I want it to be so that when I scroll within #content then article will be snapped into position.

Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("article").css("height", $(window).height() + "px");
  $("#content").sectionsnap({
    delay : 100
    , selector : 'article'
    , reference : 1
    , animationTime : 600
  });
});
```

```
(function($) {
$.fn.sectionsnap = function( options ) {

    var $wrapper = this
    , direction = 'down'
    , currentScrollTop = $("section").scrollTop()
    , scrollTimer
    , animating = false;

    // check the direction
    var updateDirection = function() {
        if ($("section").scrollTop() >= currentScrollTop)
            direction = 'down';
        else
            direction = 'up';
        currentScrollTop = $("section").scrollTop();
    }

    // return the closest element (depending on direction)
    var getClosestElement = function() {
        var $list = $wrapper.find(settings.selector)
        , wt = $("section").scrollTop()
        , wh = $("section").height()
        , refY = wh * settings.reference
        , wtd = wt + refY - 1
        , $target;

        if (direction == 'down') {
            $list.each(function() {
                var st = $(this).position().top;
                if ((st > wt) && (st <= wtd)) {
                    $target = $(this);
                    return false; // just to break the each loop
                }
            });
        } else {
            wtd = wt - refY + 1;
            $list.each(function() {
                var st = $(this).position().top;
                if ((st < wt) && (st >= wtd)) {
                    $target = $(this);
                    return false; // just to break the each loop
                }
            });
        }
        return $target;
    }

    // snap
    var snap = function() {
        var $target = getClosestElement();
        if ($target) {
            animating = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: ($target.offset().top)
                }, settings.animationTime, function() {
                    window.clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
                    animating = false;
                });
        }
    }
    // on window scroll
    $("section").scroll(windowScroll);
    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: I agree that you are not explaining this well enough

Comment: http://kuhl.pl/github/sectionsnap/ when the window scrolls, the next element comes into view immediately. I want to make it so that if the section (not the window) scrolls then the next element comes into view. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `animate()` function instead of `scrollTop()` to have the animation instead of immediate snapping from section to section.
2. Consider using easing for smooth and non-linear animation, if you'll use jQuery to do animation you can use this jQuery [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) - [ [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js) ]
3. For even smoother animation you can use other libraries like [GSAP](https://greensock.com/) or [Velocityjs](http://velocityjs.org/), both come with builtin easing functionality so you don't need to use external packages for it.
4. It's essential to make a flag, called `isScrolling` in my code, to check if currently the page is doing scrolling we should not compare the `.scrollTop()` value to the current section's `.offset().top` *until scrolling animation ends*, then we start over.

---

**Example 1:** using jQuery `.animate()` function with easing

[**jsFiddle** - editor](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/r820qs6a/)

[**jsFiddle** - fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/r820qs6a/show/)

```js
var sections = $('.sections'),
  win = $(window),
  index = 0,
  isScrolling = false;  // will be used to check whether the page is scrolling or not


// on window scroll, we capture the scroll top and the current section's top
win.on('scroll', function() {
  var winTop = win.scrollTop(),
    secTop = $(sections[index]).offset().top;

  // if page is currently scrolling, we do nothing and wait until scrolling ends
  if (!isScrolling) {

    // if is scrolling is false, and window ".scrollTop()" is more than current
   // section ".offset().top" value, we set the "isScrolling" to true so that
   // we make any scrolling decisions until the animation ends, call the animation
   // function passing the value of the next next section's ".offset().top", also 
   // increase the "index" value.
    if (winTop > secTop) {
      isScrolling = true;
      animateScrolling($(sections[index + 1]).offset().top);
      index += 1;
    }

    // same as above except we check if the window ".scrollTop()" is *less* than
    // the current section's "scrollTop()", set "isScrolling = false" and animate the
    // scroll to the previous section's "offset().top", and decrease the index value.
    if (winTop < secTop) {
      isScrolling = 1;
      animateScrolling($(sections[index - 1]).offset().top);
      index -= 1;
    }
  }
});


// instead of "win.scrollTop()" we use ".animate()" function for smooth scrolling and
// making use of a the callback function, which get executed *after* the animation
// ends, we set our scrolling flag "isScrolling" to false for further animations.
   // we use easing too, "easeInOutCubic" here, for smooth animation

function animateScrolling(secTop) {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: secTop }, 500, 'easeInOutCubic', function() {
    isScrolling = false;
  });
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.sections { width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: orange; display: block; }
.two { background-color: tomato; }
.three { background-color: skyblue; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js">
</script>
<div class="sections"></div>
<div class="sections two"></div>
<div class="sections three"></div>
```

---

**Example 2:** using GSAP `TweenMax` function with builtin easing, Although GSAP works very well with jQuery, below I used pure javascript for selecting elements instead of jQuery.

[**CodePen** - editor](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/grQqXo?editors=0010)

[**CodePen** - fullscreen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/grQqXo)

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.sections'),
  HTMLbody = document.querySelectorAll('html, body'),
  index = 0,
  isScrolling = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {   
  // Get the window scrollTop value, from:
  // stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll
  var winTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop) - (document.clientTop || 0),
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    secTop = sections[index].offsetTop;

  if (!isScrolling) {
    if (winTop > secTop) {
      isScrolling = true;
      animateScrolling(sections[index + 1].offsetTop);
      index += 1;
    }
    if (winTop < secTop) {
      isScrolling = 1;
      animateScrolling(sections[index - 1].offsetTop);
      index -= 1;
    }
  }
});

function animateScrolling(secTop) {
  TweenMax.to(HTMLbody, 0.5, {
    scrollTop: secTop,
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    onComplete: setFlagToFalse
  });
}

function setFlagToFalse() {
  isScrolling = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the scrolling isn't very smooth, and it doesn't scroll to the next section smoothly. Thank you though

Comment: @user1377298, I'm sorry that wasn't really trying to mimic the library which you provided its link, it was more like guidelines I even didn't use easing.

Comment: However, have a look at my updated answer, smooth scrolling and with easing, checking for is window scrolling, also I provided another solution using GSAP animation instead of jQuery animation.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for the suggestion. I did go off what you did, and ended up doing what I needed it to do.

Comment: I tried Example 1 and it didnt work, When I inspected the page I saw this error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at (index):801
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=20151215:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=20151215:3)

Comment: I've just tried Example1 in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, and it's working just fine with *no* errors

Comment: Hey @Mi-Creativity thank you for the useful snippet. I tried example 1 and works good. Just one thing - on my page i don't need to animate all sections just 2 and now when reaching to section which don't have the defined class am getting error of undefined. Any way i can avoid that error and have function running only for specific section? I tried to check if secTop !== undefined but not really working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: great answer, examples etc. thanks for your time and effort ;)